# spring how to use one web-environment for multiple test

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I got multiple REST APIs with multiple path. I´m currently testing those APIS with junit using the web-environment of spring to setup a http server. So I use a class which contains the following anotation and injects the port:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(ConfigConstants.PROFILE_LOCAL)
public abstract class TestBase{

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @LocalServerPort
    public int httpPort;

    ...
}
```

My test classes inherits of the `Testbase.class` and using the same port.

Setup:

- TestBase
- Class A extends TestBase
- Class B extends TestBase
- ...

In the logs I can see there is more than just one Spring Server, as the Spring ASCI Logo shows up several times.

Is there a way to start the WebEnvironment once and share those to all of my tests?

Regards
monti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to start the WebEnvironment once and share those to all of my tests?

That happens automatically, assuming you don't provide additional configuration in your subclasses that change the *context cache key*.

Details can be found in the [Context Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) section of the Spring Reference Manual.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)